# repeat php sleep method inside a foreach loop each iteration

Tags: javascript, php

I have to send around 1k emails to different customers for different issues. Normally I would get an excel file with all the necessary information to send the emails. I have a web form where I insert the ticket number and that retrieves the necessary information to send the mail (which is also provided in the excel file). The problem is that inserting 1k ticket numbers in the form is an exhausting and time consuming work. So I copied the link that is generated to send the emails and created 1k links with the specific variables needed to send 1k different emails. Now all I have to do is generate a php function to open all the links and the job is done. However the mail server does not allow more than 20 emails to be sent from the same IP at once. It marks the emails as spam and blocks the IP. I tried a `foreach` loop with php sleep function inside of it and it is not working. The function sleeps for the given amount of time and then opens all the links given at once. I want to state that the function will be run from my laptop and will not be uploaded in any server or whatsoever.

Below is the function I currently have:

```
$emails = ["http://www.facebook.com","http://www.tuttojuve.com","http://www.google.com"];
//testing with these links instead of the email links
foreach($emails as $key => $email){

    $mail = "<script type='text/javascript' language='Javascript'>window.open('".$email."','_blank');</script>";
    sleep(5);
    echo $mail; 
}
```

Any help or hint is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using cron job?

Comment: how open all at once?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy it sleeps for 5 seconds and after that all the links are opened at once in different tabs. the sleep method is not executed after the first time.

Comment: From the code it looks like you are opening new window with the link right? If this is right you should go with JavaScript not php to open new window after a specific time interval

Comment: Get all links in a json array and loop them through JavaScript;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 the problem is that there is no sleep method in javascript

Comment: You can use setInterval works same as sleep in JavaScript see my answer; :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$emails = ["http://www.facebook.com","http://www.tuttojuve.com","http://www.google.com"];
?>

<script>
    var linksToOpen = <?php echo json_encode($emails); ?>;
    var currentLink = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        window.open(linksToOpen[currentLink++], '_blank');
        /* browser popup blocker may block this window so add window url to allowed list. */
    }, 5000); 
    /* every x millisecond */
</script>
```

Comment: this solution works. however a simple improvement can be made because the after it finishes all the links in the array the function continues to open new empty tabs. besides that, well done and thank you :)